# zsh capture and pipe output to another command

Tags: zsh, xargs

I had the zsh script

```
printf '%s\0' www/scripts6/lib/* | xargs -0 -I{} -P 50 babel {} > {}
```

and it worked (i think.).  But I needed to actually copy the files to the `scripts` directory instead of `scripts6`.  Also, I needed to add an extra path to the list of paths manually, so I tried doing this:

```
paths=$(printf '%s\0' www/scripts6/lib/* | sed -e 's@www/scripts6/@@g')
paths=$paths'main.js'$'\0'
echo -n $paths | xargs -0 -I {} -P 50 babel www/scripts6/{} > www/scripts/{}
```

That was a BIG ACCOMPLISHMENT for me.  Anyway, the script makes the file named `{}` in the `scripts` directory (and nothing in the `scripts/lib` directory).  This leads me to believe that only the first `{}` in the code gets replaced by the argument, and not the second one (and I have no explanation for the absence of files in the `scripts/lib` directory).

How can I make the script work as expected?

Comment: I would like to see an `xargs` solution to this problem too, if anyone would like to share.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Redirection happens before `xargs` executes. so your first example also creates a file named `{}`, because `xargs` never got the chance to replace the last `{}`.

Also, while you do try to separate the filenames by nulls to treat filenames "correctly", the effort is in vain once you use `echo`. `echo` in `zsh` interprets the C-style escapes(\t, \n, etc) by default. You would need the -E option to disable that.

Try this and see if it does what you want

```
setopt monitor
for f in www/scripts6/lib/*(e*'REPLY=${REPLY#www/scripts6/}'*) main.js; do;
  while (( $#jobstates >= 51 )); do 
    sleep 1
  done
  echo -E babel $f \> www/scripts/$f &
done
```

If the output seems ok, remove the echo -E and replace \> with >

Comment: This is a little over my head.  I am not familiar with setopt, monitor, or jobstates.  Does your script wait for all jobs to complete before moving on?  Also, if other jobs were launched before the script, do they become one of the "jobstates" too?

Comment: The loop does not wait until all children exit, you can add wait below the final done to achieve that. If you were to send additional processes into the background before the loop, _inside_ of the script; they would be counted in jobstates.